# Stop a long-running action in web2py with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, session, web2py, kill-process

I have a web2py application that basically serves as a browser interface for a Python script. This script usually returns pretty quickly, but can occasionally take a long time. I want to provide a way for the user to stop the script's execution if it takes too long.

I am currently calling the function like this:

```
def myView():  # this function is called from ajax
    session.model = myFunc()  # myFunc is from a module which i have complete control over
    return dict(model=session.model)
```

`myFunc`, when called with certain options, uses multiprocessing but still ends up taking a long time. I need some way to terminate the function, or at the very least the thread's children.

The first thing i tried was to run `myFunc` in a new process, and roll my own simple event system to kill it:

```
# in the controller
def myView():
    p_conn, c_conn = multiprocessing.Pipe()
    events = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=_fit, args=(options, events c_conn))
    proc.start()
    sleep(0.01)
    session.events = events
    proc.join()
    session.model = p_conn.recv()
    return dict(model=session.model)

def _fit(options, events pipe):
    pipe.send(fitting.logistic_fit(options=options, events=events))
    pipe.close()

def stop():
    try:
        session.events['kill']()
    except SystemExit:
        pass  # because it raises that error intentionally
    return dict()

# in the module
def kill():
    print multiprocessing.active_children()
    for p in multiprocessing.active_children():
        p.terminate()
    raise SystemExit

def myFunc(options, events):
    events['kill'] = kill
```

I ran into a few major problems with this.

1. The session in `stop()` wasn't always the same as the session in `myView()`, so `session.events` was None.
2. Even when the session was the same, `kill()` wasn't properly killing the children.
3. The long-running function would hang the web2py thread, so `stop()` wasn't even processed until the function finished.

I considered not calling `join()` and using AJAX to pick up the result of the function at a later time, but I wasn't able to save the process object in `session` for later use. The pipe seemed to be able to be pickled, but then I had the problem with not being able to access the same session from another view.

How can I implement this feature?

Answer (score 1):

For long running tasks, you are better off queuing them via the built-in [scheduler](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#web2py-Scheduler). If you want to allow the user to manually stop a task that is taking too long, you can use the `scheduler.stop_task(ref)` method (where `ref` is the task `id` or `uuid`). Alternatively, when you queue a task, you can specify a timeout, so it will automatically stop if not completed within the timeout period.

You can do simple Ajax polling to notify the client when the task has completed (or implement something more sophisticated with websockets or SSE).

Comment: Can you please expand upon your answer? Some specific things that would be worth answering: Does the scheduler start the task immediately, from a script? How to get the result of the task? How to force-stop the task? As it is, this doesn't completely answer the question.

Comment: I have updated the answer to address your last question. Your first two questions are addressed in the linked documentation. As they involve general scheduler functionality and are not part of your original question, I won't update the answer, but I will briefly mention that by default new tasks are queued immediately (and you can force a worker to immediately check the queue by setting `immediate=True`), and the `scheduler.task_status()` method is used to retrieve results.